# Как перезапустить webpack?

Tags: webpack

В терминале выводится:

```
webpack: compiled successfully
```

Добавил стилей, нужно перезапустить `webpack`, как я понимаю, чтобы заработало.

Answer (score 0):

У этой системы есть параметр `watch`, который будет постоянно следить за изменениями в файлах и, в случае изменения, пересобирать их.
Так же есть дополнение, которое называется `webpak-dev-server`, который предоставляет дополнительный функционал в виде веб-сервера с `liveReload`.

```
webpack --watch
```

Либо можно установить `webpack-dev-server` и использовать его:

```
webpack-dev-server --content-base [путь к папке в которую собирается проект] --host localhost --port 80
```